# Building jQuery plugin with multiple settings

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am building a jQuery plugin, my plugin works well but I cannot work out the syntax to "group the default settings" into desktop, mobile, iphone. I could do an if statement based on the value of the variable but I am trying to give users the option to choose what devices they would like to load from the plugin. Below is the code that I am using to build the plugin's settings:

```
;(function($, window, document, undefined){

    //define JQDPT object with some default config settings
    $.JQDPT = {
        defaults: {
            type: "desktop",
            imgContainer: "",
            imgFormat: "jpg",
            sidebar: "#sidebar",
            imgDir: ""
        }
    };
```

On my index.html page, I initialise the plugin like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


        $("#jqdptcontainer").JQDPT({ 
        type: "desktop",
        imgContainer:"jqdptcontainer",
        imgDir: "images/", }, 
        ["Homepage", "Categories", "Product_description"]
        );

</script>
```

But I cannot figure out the syntax to group parameters in my plugin, I would like something like the below this is >>incorrect, but only an example of what I would like to achieve:

```
;(function($, window, document, undefined){

    //define JQDPT object with some default config settings
    $.JQDPT = {
        defaults: {
                       type: desktop, {
                                        imgContainer: "",
                                        imgFormat: "jpg",
                                        sidebar: "#sidebar",
                                        imgDir: ""
                                       },
                       type: ipad, {
                                        imgContainer: "",
                                        imgFormat: "jpg",
                                        sidebar: "#sidebar",
                                        imgDir: ""
                                       },
                       type: mobile, {
                                        imgContainer: "",
                                        imgFormat: "jpg",
                                        sidebar: "#sidebar",
                                        imgDir: ""
                                       },

        }
    };
```

Also, what would be the correct syntax to initialise the plugin with grouped settings on the index.html page, to initialise the updated plugin? ie:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


        $("#jqdptcontainer").JQDPT({ 
        type: "desktop",{
                         imgContainer:"jqdptcontainer",
                         imgDir: "images/", }, 
                              ["Homepage", "Categories", "Product_description"]},
            type: "iphone",{
                         imgContainer:"jqdptcontainer",
                         imgDir: "images/", }, 
                              ["Homepage", "Categories", "Product_description"]},

        );
```

I have spent countless hours on jquery.com to look at other plugins and there are nuggets of information but I can't figure out the syntax yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.JQDPT = {
    defaults: {
                   desktop : {
                                    imgContainer: "",
                                    imgFormat: "jpg",
                                    sidebar: "#sidebar",
                                    imgDir: "", 
                                    arrayOfSomething : []
                                   },
                   ipad : {
                                    imgContainer: "",
                                    imgFormat: "jpg",
                                    sidebar: "#sidebar",
                                    imgDir: "", 
                                    arrayOfSomething : []
                                   },
                   mobile : {
                                    imgContainer: "",
                                    imgFormat: "jpg",
                                    sidebar: "#sidebar",
                                    imgDir: "", 
                                    arrayOfSomething : []
                                   },

    }
};


    $("#jqdptcontainer").JQDPT({ 
    "desktop" :{
                     imgContainer:"jqdptcontainer",
                     imgDir: "images/", 
                     arrayOfSomething : ["Homepage", "Categories", "Product_description"]},
        "iphone" : {
                     imgContainer:"jqdptcontainer",
                     imgDir: "images/", 
                     arrayOfSomething : ["Homepage", "Categories", "Product_description"]},

    );
```

You can reference the options this way.

```
var o = $.extend(true, $.JQDPT.defaults, passedInOptions);
console.log(o);
console.log(o.desktop);
console.log(o.ipad);
console.log(o.mobile);
```

This is not valid

```
              imgDir: "images/", }, 
                          ["Homepage", "Categories", "Product_description"]},
```

The array of Strings (Homepage, etc) should be giving you a javascript error?

Hope that helps.